# What are the rules for soccer/football goalies committing penalties inside the box?

Tags: football

During the recent Women's World Cup Quarter-Final, the French goalie performed a slide tackle inside the box against an attacker. She completely missed the ball and tripped the attacker. Why wasn't this a penalty? I'll try to attach a clip if I can find one.

I found a pay-walled (but readable) [two-part article discussing goalie behavior](https://www.socceramerica.com/publications/article/73103/violent-goalkeeping-part-1-players-at-risk-as-s.html) that indicates this is a well-known problem in all of soccer.

Comment: France got knocked out in the quarter finals. What game are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I meant quarter final, but I wad think about the game that was coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the referee thought that the slide tackle was a foul it would have still been a penalty. However, referee's are often much more lenient towards goalie's fouling attackers. Goalie's have gotten red cards before if the commit a foul and have the same rules applied to them as field players. Perhaps the forward "flopped" or pretended to get hit causing the referee to not give a penalty.